# Increase Size Of DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

I am using DatePickerDialog, and it just seems like it isn't scaling correctly on my Note 5. It appears fairly small in the center of the screen. Is there a way to tell DatePickerDialog to use 90% of the screen? See my code below:

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:minWidth="800dp"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtContract"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Contract #"
        android:inputType="text" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtTrip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Trip #"
        android:inputType="text" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtDate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Date"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:inputType="date" >
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSend"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Start Trip" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Main:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText txtContract;
    EditText txtTrip;
    EditText txtDate;
    private static final String CONTRACT_REGEX = "^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]){5}$";
    private static final String TRIP_REGEX = "^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]){1,10}$";
    private static final String DATE_REGEX = "^\\d{2}\\/\\d{2}\\/\\d{4}$";
    private static final String PHONE_NUMBER = "1234567890";

    Button btnSend;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {

            // Initialize Views
            txtContract = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtContract);
            txtTrip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTrip);
            txtDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
            btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);

            // Set Listeners
            txtDate.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnSend.setOnClickListener(this);

            // Check If Device Is Capable Of Sending SMS
            PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
            if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY) && !pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY_CDMA)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, your device probably can't send SMS...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error in MainActivity.onCreate: " + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Handle Clicked View
        switch (v.getId()) {

            // Date Field
            case R.id.txtDate:

                // Get Current Date
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                // Set Up DatePicker Dialog
                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

                        // Define Calendar For Formatting
                        final Calendar cf = Calendar.getInstance();

                        // Format Selected Date
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
                        cf.set(year,month,day);
                        String selectedDate = sdf.format(cf.getTime());

                        // Add Selected Date To EditText Field
                        txtDate.setText(selectedDate);
                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

                // Set Max Date
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());

                // Set Min Date
                c.add(Calendar.DATE,-4);
                datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());

                // Display DatePicker
                datePickerDialog.show();
            break;

            // Submit Button
            case R.id.btnSend:

                // Define Variables
                String strContract;
                String strTrip;
                String strDate;
                String strMessage;
                SmsManager sms;
                Boolean rval = true;

                // Get Input Strings
                strContract = txtContract.getText().toString();
                strTrip = txtTrip.getText().toString();
                strDate = txtDate.getText().toString();

                // Validate
                if (!Validation.isValid(txtContract, CONTRACT_REGEX, "Invalid Contract #", true)) rval = false;
                if (!Validation.isValid(txtTrip, TRIP_REGEX, "Invalid Trip #", true)) rval = false;
                if (!Validation.isValid(txtDate,DATE_REGEX,"Invalid Date",true)) rval = false;

                // Build Message
                strMessage = strContract.concat("|").concat(strTrip).concat("|").concat(strDate);

                // Continue If We Pass Validation
                if (rval) {

                    try {
                        // Send SMS
                        sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        sms.sendTextMessage(PHONE_NUMBER, null, strMessage, null, null);

                        // Display Message
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Sent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // Clear Fields
                    txtContract.setText("");
                    txtTrip.setText("");
                    txtDate.setText("");

                }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a Dialog with a custom view. In the custom view inflate a linear layout (with inside a date picker) but with a fixed width. You can calculate the needed width getting your display resolution.

Comment: Saret, I appreciate your input. However, I must admit I am fairly new to android development. Would you be kind enough to give me some sort of direction with an example?

Comment: final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdialog_layout); add in your customdialog a linearlayout with a child (date picker) set android:layout_width="your width" and the same for the height